# React useImperativeHandle and forwardRef being set, the reference doesn't seem to be updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forwardref

I need to access the location of a child component. For what I understand, to access the child properties, I need to use `useImperativeHandle` to add the child API to its ref. Moreover, I need to use `forwardRef` to transmit the reference from the parent to the child. So I did this:

```js
const Text = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => {
  const componentAPI = {};
  componentAPI.getLocation = () => {
    return ref.current.getBoundingClientRect ? ref.current.getBoundingClientRect() : 'nope'
  };
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => componentAPI);
  return (<button onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>Press Me</button>);
});

Text.displayName = "Text";

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null)

  return (<div>
    <Text onClick={() => setValue(ref.current.getLocation())} ref={ref} />
    <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As you can see, the ref doesn't have the `getBoundingClientRect` property, but if I do this it will work as expected:

```js
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null)

  return (<div>
      <button ref={ref} onClick={() => setValue(ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()) } ref={ref}>Press Me</button>
      <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So what is wrong with my understanding of `useImperativeHanedle` and `forwardRef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `useImperativeHandle` you need to work with another `ref` instance like so:

```
const Text = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef();

  React.useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      getLocation: () => buttonRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    }),
    [buttonRef]
  );

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} ref={buttonRef}>
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
});
```

If you want **your logic** to be valid (using the same forwarded `ref`), this will work:

```
const Text = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.getLocation = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect;
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      Press Me
    </button>
  );
});
```

Why your example doesn't work?

Because `ref.current.getBoundingClientRect` not available in a moment of assigning it in `useImperativeHandle` (try logging it) because you actually overridden the button's `ref` with `useImperativeHandle` (Check `Text3` in sandbox, the `ref.current` value has `getLocation` assigned after the mount).

[image: Edit admiring-darkness-o8bm4]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain why? I don't see what is actually going on that prevents my solution to work.

Comment: On your second example, wouldn't I risk to lose the getLocation function if the `ref.current` value gets updated ?

Comment: I updated the answer and yes, it is a risk (which you can handle), it just an example for how your logic might work, never seen such code in practice

Comment: But `buttonRef.current.getBoundingClientRect` is not available either, is it? This is where I don't see the difference...

Comment: I was mistaken, let me fix the answer

Comment: Check the answer, I'm was surprised from the result too, you have all examples in the sandbox attached.

Comment: Ok, I reported the issue to React. Check my answer below to see how things could be made easier. Thanks for your time. You answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)(maybe not understandable enough), the child component itself should have a different ref, and by useImperativeHandle you can define a function mapping forwardedRef to child ref:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const Text = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef() // create a new ref for button
  const componentAPI = {};
  componentAPI.getLocation = () => {
    return buttonRef.current.getBoundingClientRect ? buttonRef.current.getBoundingClientRect() : 'nope' // use buttonRef here
  };
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => componentAPI); // this maps ref to buttonRef now
  return (<button onClick={onClick} ref={buttonRef}>Press Me</button>); // set buttonRef
});

Text.displayName = "Text";

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null)

  return (<div>
    <Text onClick={() => setValue(ref.current.getLocation())} ref={ref} />
    <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this answer to show how things can become easier when removing useless overcontrol...

```js
const Text = React.forwardRef(({ onClick }, ref) => {
  ref.getLocation = () => ref.current && ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()
  return (<button onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>Press Me</button>);
});

Text.displayName = "Text";

function App() {
  const ref = { current: null };
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null)
  return (<div>
    <Text onClick={() => setValue(ref.getLocation())} ref={ref} />
    <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
  </div>);
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

In the code above, we just use forwardRef and attach the child API to it's ref, which seems very natural in the end, and very userfriendly.

The only thing that would prevent you using this is that React.createRef makes a call to `Object.preventExtension()` (thanks for making my life harder...), so the hack is to use `{ current: null }` instead of `Object.createRef()` (which is basically the same).