# The order of re-render and useEffect() called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component `TopPage` and `ImagePreview` and `FileUploader`

1. At first `FileUploader` is shown,
2. FileUploader changed the fileObj state of TopPage.
3. then,FileUploader disappeared and ImagePreview appreas, and at the same time useEffect() is called, but at this time, there is no `ImagePreviewRef`.

When useState is called , both component re-render and useEffect are called.

The order is useEffect -> re-render?

If so, how can I solve this problem?

```
const TopPage = (props) =>{
    const [fileObj, setFileObj ] = useState();
    const imagePreviewRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log("useEffect() is called with fileObj:",fileObj);
        console.log("imagePrevireRef.current is ready?",imagePreviewRef.current);
        imagePreviewRef.current.loadPic(fileObj);
    },[fileObj]);

    if (fileObj){
      return <ImagePreview ref={imagePreviewRef}></ImagePreview>
    }
    else {
      return <FileUploader SetFileObj=setFileObj></FileUploader>
    }
}

const FileUploader = (props) => {
   // props.setFileObj() is called here.
}
const ImagePreview = (props) => {
   const loadPic = () =>{// loadpicture to canvas }   
}
```

---

Temporary solution,

Currently I did like this,
Rendering both `ImagePreview` and `FileUploader`
components from the beginning and swith them by `display:none`.

It looks like a bit awkward... but it works well for now.

```
const TopPage = (props) =>{
    const [fileObj, setFileObj ] = useState();
    const imagePreviewRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log("useEffect() is called with fileObj:",fileObj);
        console.log("imagePrevireRef.current is ready?",imagePreviewRef.current);
        imagePreviewRef.current.loadPic(fileObj);
    },[fileObj]);

    if (fileObj){
      return 
<React.Fragment>
<div style={{display:"block"}}>
<ImagePreview ref={imagePreviewRef}></ImagePreview>
</div>
<div style={{display:"none"}}>
<FileUploader SetFileObj=setFileObj></FileUploader>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
    }
    else {
      return 
<React.Fragment>
<div style={{display:"none"}}>
<FileUploader SetFileObj=setFileObj></FileUploader>
</div>
<div style={{display:"block"}}>
<ImagePreview ref={imagePreviewRef}></ImagePreview>
</div>
</React.Fragment>
    }
}

const FileUploader = (props) => {
   // props.setFileObj() is called here.
}
const ImagePreview = (props) => {
   const loadPic = () =>{// loadpicture to canvas }   
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` always runs after the component is rendered. Since you are conditionally rendering based on `fileObj` you should also be conditionally operating on the `ref` so `useEffect(() => {  if (fileObj) { imagePreviewRef.current.loadPic(fileObj); }, [fileObj]);`. But I don't see where you are declaring `imagePreviewRef`.

Comment: I added the ImagePrevireRef declaring.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however in my case even when `fileObj` is exist, there is not `imagePrevireRef`.

Comment: see: [React useImperativeHandle and forwardRef being set, the reference doesn't seem to be updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599895/react-useimperativehandle-and-forwardref-being-set-the-reference-doesnt-seem-t) and the React docs: [useImperativeHandle](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle)

Comment: "*even when `fileObj` is exist, there is not `imagePrevireRef`*" - are you sure there? How do you know this, what logging or debugging have you done? Afaict, the problem rather would be that there is no `imagePreviewRef.current` *until* the `fileObj` state is filled, but the effect runs immediately (when the `<TopPage>` still renders only the `<FileUploader>`) anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the article I useed console.log and checked. Even when `fileObj` is set, `imagePreviewRef.current` is `undefined`

Comment: Btw, why put the `useEffect` in the `TopPage`, not inside the `ImagePreview`?

Comment: Ah! `ImagePreview` must have the fileObj? It might be the origin of problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unify the render and then show the components conditionally with CSS to keep the reference.

```
const TopPage = (props) =>{
    const [fileObj, setFileObj ] = useState();
    const imagePreviewRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() =>{
       if(imagePreviewRef.current)
        imagePreviewRef.current.loadPic(fileObj);
    },[fileObj]);

    return (
      <> 
       <div style={{ display: fileObj ? 'block' : 'hidden' }}>
         <ImagePreview ref={imagePreviewRef}/> 
       </div>
        {fileObj && <FileUploader SetFileObj={setFileObj}/> }
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unify the render". Why are you still rendering the `<FileUploader>` when it is no longer needed?

Comment: My mistake, I updated it the answer

Comment: @genesis Thank you for your comment , your idea gives me the hint , display `block` and `hidden`(none?) works well for my case.